# Add icon to navigation drawer Android

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I don't know how to add icons to a drawer.

Here is where I need the images (highlight in red):
[image]

I have being following this tutorial.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android

Comment: Please follow this tutorial 

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I followed it but the action is deprecated

Comment: Please follow [this updated version of this step-by-step tutorial](http://androidgifts.com/navigation-view-using-design-support-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change navList adapter to customize each row. Then you can create customize layout for row item, and you can add icon or whatever. In this tutorial teach how to did it:

- http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

For add icon in the action bar, there are several methods, one of this is customize action bar layout with a xml view, like this:

```
View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_view, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve images in navigation drawer like this:

Add a class with name some thing like DataStore:

```
public class DataStore {

    int iconId;
    String title;
}
```

Then in navigation drawer fragment use it as shown below:

```
public static List<DataStore> getData() {

        List<DataStore> data = new ArrayList<>();

        int[] icons = {R.mipmap.icon1, R.mipmap.icon2, R.mipmap.icon3, R.mipmap.icon4, R.mipmap.icon5};
        String[] titles = {"Title1", "title2", "Title3", "Title4", "title5"};

        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++) {

            DataStore current = new DataStore();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.title = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

For action bar icons. In the respective activities menu screen you can define an icon and then use them.

Hope it helps.